# How to Escape Semicolon in Sql

Tags: java, sql, scala, playframework

How to escape semicolon in Sql ? I used playframework i tried to insert html code inside "values" but when i try using semicolon it's not working ?

```
    CREATE TABLE "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE"
    (
        "ID" uuid NOT NULL,
        "WP_ID" uuid NOT NULL,
        "CODE" text NOT NULL,
        "SUBJECT" text NOT NULL,
        "CONTENT" text NOT NULL,
        "CREATED_AT" timestamp without time zone,
        "CREATED_BY" text,
        "UPDATED_AT" timestamp without time zone,
        "UPDATED_BY" text,
        CONSTRAINT "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
        CONSTRAINT "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_WP_pkey" FOREIGN KEY ("WP_ID") REFERENCES "C_WP" ("ID")
    );
    INSERT INTO "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE"
        VALUES (
            '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebc4',
            '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebcf',
            'user-activation',
            'User Registration',
            ';',
            '2018-05-17 19:02:39.643',
            'LOGIN',
            null,
            null
        );
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: im giving up, i replace css ; with single line css tag

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon does not need to be escaped.
It looks like problem is not about semicolon, but about double quotes you used in second INSERT

String values in SQL must be in single quotes. Double quote is reserved for object names such as schema/tables/columns names etc.

so try

```
INSERT INTO "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE"
 VALUES (
    '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebc4',
    '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebcf',
    'user-activation',
    'User Registration',
    ';',
    '2018-05-17 19:02:39.643',
    'LOGIN',
    null,
    null
);
```

instead...

Comment: still not working i changed from ' to " because i think if i use " semicolon will work

Comment: This answer no longer applies to the current version of the question. It was originally posted with double quotation marks and changed to singles after receiving this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use \ to set escape character and try following:

```
INSERT INTO "R_EMAIL_TEMPLATE"
 VALUES (
    '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebc4',
    '30abd6ec-3496-45ff-be54-7f6f9290ebcf',
    'user-activation',
    'User Registration',
    '\;',
    '2018-05-17 19:02:39.643',
    'LOGIN',
    null,
    null
);
```

Comment: "\. Expected " char [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601]

Comment: Which database your using?

Comment: im using postgres sql

Comment: try q quotes like  q'[ ; ]'

Comment: oh god why q'[. Expected char

Comment: i tried same script laravel before and is work fine, but when in scala ouch its hurt